# Jquery not working in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am new in Angular2. I have done this once, but when I am trying to set up the same environment in my home PC, I am unable to do this.

In my **add-page.component.ts**, I am declaring `$` and `jquery` like this:-

```
declare var $ : any;
declare var jquery : any;
```

Then in the `ngAfterViewInit` function, I am running this jquery.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    $(function(){
        if($('#desc').length>0)
        {
            $("#desc").Editor();  
            $(".Editor-editor").html($('#desc').text());
            $("#desc").val($('.Editor-editor').html()); 
        }
    });
}
```

However, the jquery isn't working. When I am writing `alert('Hi')` inside `ngAfterViewInit()` but outside `$(document).ready(function(){})`, I am getting the alert. But alert inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` isn't working. So, that means the `ngAfterViewInit` is working but not the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

By the way, jquery library is added in the **index.html** file:-

```
<script src="assets/admin-assets/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should use **<script src="/assets/admin-assets/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>**

Comment: is it showing any errors in the console? have you tried running any other code, like `alert('ready');`, inside `.ready()` and c if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line of code:

```
declare var jquery : any;
```

Also make sure that you importing ngAfterViewInit from angular using this line of code:

```
import { ngAfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
```

also make sure that you jquery file exists in the components folder, if you don't know how, try to use the CDN by changing the reference to be `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"` instead in your script tag.

Comment: Yes, I have `import { ngAfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';` in my component file.

Comment: Did you try the CDN for jquery?

Comment: I tried the CDN too. The problem was with a jquery code in an additional external file. Fixing that solved the problem.